# How to change environment variable when the option is inactive

Tags: windows, environment-variables

I'm trying to change the environment variable in windows 8, however the option  to change is inactive.

I tried to change the PATH using the command line, however the path never updated when I closed the command line.

I'm using an administrator account.

Is there anyone who encountered such problem ?

[image]

---

Update, Thanks to @David, I tried the cmd command:

```
SETX PATH=%PATH%;"D:\Shahar\CodingLibraries\opencv\build\x86\vc10\bin"
```

Please note that I'm using brackets and there are no spaces in this path ( the path exists on my computer )

Now I get an error from the command line

```
ERROR: Invalid syntax. Default option is not allowed  more than '2' time<s>
```

Which is usually refer when you have space in the new path.

[image]

Beside, when I try:

```
SETX = PATH=%PATH%
```

I get the same error.

Any suggestion  what should I do next ?

---

Update 2, I changed to command according to @Daniel

Now the command is the following

```
SETX PATH="%PATH%;D:\Shahar\CodingLibraries\opencv\" /m
```

I get an error

```
Invalid syntax
```

[image]

I tried the follow,

```
SETX PATH="%PATH%;D:\Shahar\CodingLibraries\opencv\"
```

I got the same error,

I tried:

```
SETX PATH="%PATH%"
```

I still get a syntax error ... I'm  nearly giving up on this...

I tried the same command with back slashes

```
SETX PATH="%PATH%;D:/Shahar/CodingLibraries/opencv/" /M
```

Now I get an error that the Length of the command line argument should not exceed 255 characters

Any suggestions on what to do next ? Does the PATH is limit by 255 characters or that's a cmd command limitation ?

[image]

Comment: Your command is **still** wrong. There should be no `=`. See my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### I tried to change the PATH it using the command line, however the path never updated

If you use `set` to change an environment variable the changes are only valid for the current command shell.

- `set` - Display, set, or remove CMD environment variables. Changes made with SET will remain only for the duration of the current CMD session.

To make a permanent change use `setx` instead.

- `setx` - Set environment variables permanently, SETX can be used to set Environment Variables for the machine (HKLM) or currently logged on user (HKCU)

---

#### I got "ERROR: Invalid syntax. Default option is not allowed  more than '2' times"

Your command was:

```
SETX PATH=%PATH%;"D:\Shahar\CodingLibraries\opencv\buil\x86\vc10\bin"
```

The syntax of the above command is incorrect.

**To set the user path**:

```
SETX PATH "%PATH%;D:\Shahar\CodingLibraries\opencv\build\x86\vc10\bin"
```

**To set the system path**:

```
SETX PATH "%PATH%;D:\Shahar\CodingLibraries\opencv\build\x86\vc10\bin" /m
```

---

#### Further reading

- [set - Display, set, or remove CMD environment variables](http://ss64.com/nt/set.html).
- [setx - Set environment variables permanently](http://ss64.com/nt/setx.html)

Comment: @TripleS Your command syntax was incorrect, answer updated.